# Control surface effect

Tags: aerodynamics

If we know the Center of Mass and the Center of Lift, and the position and rotation of some control surface, how can we calculate what [control surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_control_surfaces) must be operated to change our path?

lets say we have two aileron, how their contribute change if i translate and rotate them?

Comment: your question is too vague and aviation SE http://aviation.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for it anyway

Comment: maybe math (linear geometry) is even better.

Comment: What you're asking is really basic aircraft controls. There's no calculation required. Center of mass should be forward of center of lift. Ailerons control rate of bank, and bank controls rate of turn. Elevators control speed, and throttle controls rate of ascent or descent.

Comment: I'm not asking that, I'm asking given the position of the surface how can I get the effect it has on translation/rotation

Comment: Read the answer to [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/7734/how-can-i-calculate-the-rolling-moment-of-an-aileron-for-a-given-plane-based-on) over at Aviation SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a diagram. If your control surface increases lift at a point, add a force pointing up. That force, if it does not go through the center of gravity, will add a torque to the system. The direction of that torque can be seen directly from the diagram.

Comment: I need to do it mathematically, with logic I get it

Comment: Torque is the cross product of distance and force vectors - giving you both magnitude and direction of the result.

Comment: I see, it is very simple now. then if the surface is not flat the force vector will take into account that. BUT what if a surface is a motor, for example a quad?

Comment: @lesto more or less yes. Of course the amount of force generated by a control surface is not an easy thing to calculate accurately - but this is not the place to try to explore that in detail.

Comment: Yes, I need only a raw estimation, but now I see what was the real question: what if it is an propeller engine (like a multicopter) instead of a control surface? Then the trust of the motor/propeller can generate a transaction, and not only a rotation